# Is HTML attribute keytype deprecate?

Tags: html

HTML tag `keygen`is now officially [deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#the-keygen-element).

HTML attribute `keytype` belongs to **only** HTML tag `keygen`: in this case (attribute with only one tag that becames deprecated/obsolete), is there an **explicit** deprecation for the attribute too ? If yes, where I found that declaration about HTML attribute `keytype`?
(or that attribute is left forever tag's "orphan" without ever taking an explicit position on its deprecated/obsolete state?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keytype attribute is defined only as part of the definition of the keygen element. Thus any deprecation of the keygen element section of the specification covers the keytype attribute too.